adding attention mechanism to yolo algorithm
i'm trying to add Cbam attention mechanism to yolo architecture
this is my Cbam implementation added to common.py
class ChannelAttention(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_planes, ratio=16):
        """
        Initialize the Channel Attention module.
        Args:
            in_planes (int): Number of input channels.
            ratio (int): Reduction ratio for the hidden channels in the channel attention block.
        """
        super(ChannelAttention, self).__init__()
        self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
        self.max_pool = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d(1)
        self.f1 = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, in_planes // ratio, 1, bias=False)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.f2 = nn.Conv2d(in_planes // ratio, in_planes, 1, bias=False)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Forward pass of the Channel Attention module.
        Args:
            x (torch.Tensor): Input tensor.
        Returns:
            out (torch.Tensor): Output tensor after applying channel attention.
        """
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
            avg_out = self.f2(self.relu(self.f1(self.avg_pool(x))))
            max_out = self.f2(self.relu(self.f1(self.max_pool(x))))
            out = self.sigmoid(avg_out + max_out)
            return out


# contributed by @aash1999
class SpatialAttention(nn.Module):
  
    def __init__(self, kernel_size=7):
        """
        Initialize the Spatial Attention module.
        Args:
            kernel_size (int): Size of the convolutional kernel for spatial attention.
        """
        print(f"Initializing SpatialAttention with kernel_size={kernel_size}")
        print('hello')

        super(SpatialAttention, self).__init__()

        print(f"Initializing SpatialAttention with kernel_size={kernel_size}")

        
        assert kernel_size in (3, 7), 'kernel size must be 3 or 7'
        padding = 3 if kernel_size == 7 else 1
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(2, 1, kernel_size, padding=padding, bias=False)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Forward pass of the Spatial Attention module.
        Args:
            x (torch.Tensor): Input tensor.
        Returns:
            out (torch.Tensor): Output tensor after applying spatial attention.
        """
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
            avg_out = torch.mean(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
            max_out, _ = torch.max(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
            x = torch.cat([avg_out, max_out], dim=1)
            x = self.conv(x)
            return self.sigmoid(x)


# contributed by @aash1999
class CBAM(nn.Module):
    # ch_in, ch_out, shortcut, groups, expansion, ratio, kernel_size
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, kernel_size=3, shortcut=True, g=1, e=0.5, ratio=16):
        """
        Initialize the CBAM (Convolutional Block Attention Module) .
        Args:
            c1 (int): Number of input channels.
            c2 (int): Number of output channels.
            kernel_size (int): Size of the convolutional kernel.
            shortcut (bool): Whether to use a shortcut connection.
            g (int): Number of groups for grouped convolutions.
            e (float): Expansion factor for hidden channels.
            ratio (int): Reduction ratio for the hidden channels in the channel attention block.
        """
        super().__init__()
        c_ = int(c2 * e)  # hidden channels
        self.cv1 = Conv(c1, c_, 1, 1)
        self.cv2 = Conv(c_, c2, 3, 1, g=g)
        self.add = shortcut and c1 == c2
        self.channel_attention = ChannelAttention(c2, ratio)
        self.spatial_attention = SpatialAttention(kernel_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Forward pass of the CBAM .
        Args:
            x (torch.Tensor): Input tensor.
        Returns:
            out (torch.Tensor): Output tensor after applying the CBAM bottleneck.
        """
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
            x2 = self.cv2(self.cv1(x))
            out = self.channel_attention(x2) * x2
            out = self.spatial_attention(out) * out
            return x + out if self.add else out

this is my yolov5sCbum.yaml (all kernel_size are 3):
# Ultralytics YOLOv5 , AGPL-3.0 license

# Parameters
nc: 80 # number of classes
depth_multiple: 0.33 # model depth multiple
width_multiple: 0.50 # layer channel multiple
anchors:
  - [10, 13, 16, 30, 33, 23] # P3/8
  - [30, 61, 62, 45, 59, 119] # P4/16
  - [116, 90, 156, 198, 373, 326] # P5/32

# YOLOv5 v6.0 backbone
backbone:
  [
    [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 6, 2, 2]],    # 0-P1/2
    [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 2]],      # 1-P2/4
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [128, 128, 3]],    # CBAM after Conv layer
    [-1, 3, C3, [128]],              # 2
    [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],      # 3-P3/8
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [256, 256, 3]],    # CBAM after Conv block for mid-level features
    [-1, 6, C3, [256]],              # 4
    [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 2]],      # 5-P4/16
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [512, 512, 3]],    # CBAM after Conv block for high-level features
    [-1, 9, C3, [512]],              # 6
    [-1, 1, Conv, [1024, 3, 2]],     # 7-P5/32
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [1024, 1024, 3]],  # CBAM for deep features
    [-1, 3, C3, [1024]],             # 8
    [-1, 1, SPPF, [1024, 5]],        # 9
  ]

# YOLOv5 v6.0 head
head:
  [
    [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]],                # 10
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [512, 512, 3]],              # Add CBAM before Upsampling
    [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],# 11
    [[-1, 6], 1, Concat, [1]],                 # 12 cat backbone P4
    [-1, 3, C3, [512, False]],                 # 13
    [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],                # 14
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [256, 256, 3]],              # Add CBAM after Conv block before upsampling
    [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],# 15
    [[-1, 4], 1, Concat, [1]],                 # 16 cat backbone P3
    [-1, 3, C3, [256, False]],                 # 17 (P3/8-small)
    [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],                # 18
    [[-1, 13], 1, Concat, [1]],                # 19 cat head P4
    [-1, 3, C3, [512, False]],                 # 20 (P4/16-medium)
    [-1, 1, CBAM, [512, 512, 3]],              # CBAM after C3 block before concatenating features
    [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 2]],                # 21
    [[-1, 10], 1, Concat, [1]],                # 22 cat head P5
    [-1, 3, C3, [1024, False]],                # 23 (P5/32-large)
    [[17, 20, 23], 1, Detect, [nc, anchors]],  # 24 Detect(P3, P4, P5)
  ]

and this is the modification of parser in yolo.py:
if m in {
            Conv,
            GhostConv,
            Bottleneck,
            GhostBottleneck,
            SPP,
            SPPF,
            DWConv,
            MixConv2d,
            Focus,
            CrossConv,
            BottleneckCSP,
            C3,
            C3TR,
            C3SPP,
            C3Ghost,
            nn.ConvTranspose2d,
            DWConvTranspose2d,
            C3x,
            CBAM
            
        }:
            c1, c2 = ch[f], args[0]
            if c2 != no:  # if not output
                c2 = make_divisible(c2 * gw, ch_mul)

            args = [c1, c2, *args[1:]]
            if m in {BottleneckCSP, C3, C3TR, C3Ghost, C3x}:
                args.insert(2, n)  # number of repeats
                n = 1

            if m == CBAM:
                # Ensure you're passing the correct kernel size from args
                print(f"CBAM args: {args}")  # Debug to print CBAM arguments
                args = args[:3]  # c1, c2, kernel_size (since CBAM takes only these three args)

But i face the bellow error:
                 from  n    params  module                                  arguments                     
  0                -1  1      3520  models.common.Conv                      [3, 32, 6, 2, 2]              
  1                -1  1     18560  models.common.Conv                      [32, 64, 3, 2]                

CBAM args: [64, 64, 128, 3]
Initializing SpatialAttention with kernel_size=128

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/train.py", line 986, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/train.py", line 688, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/train.py", line 216, in train
    model = Model(cfg or ckpt["model"].yaml, ch=3, nc=nc, anchors=hyp.get("anchors")).to(device)  # create
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/models/yolo.py", line 245, in __init__
    self.model, self.save = parse_model(deepcopy(self.yaml), ch=[ch])  # model, savelist
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/models/yolo.py", line 466, in parse_model
    m_ = nn.Sequential(*(m(*args) for _ in range(n))) if n > 1 else m(*args)  # module
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/models/common.py", line 171, in __init__
    self.spatial_attention = SpatialAttention(kernel_size)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis/yolov5/models/common.py", line 128, in __init__
    assert kernel_size in (3, 7), 'kernel size must be 3 or 7'
AssertionError: kernel size must be 3 or 7

I defined the CBAM module with [128, 128, 3] args but the parser output is [64, 64, 128, 3]. why?
How do we manage each layer's arguments to avoid errors like this?
